# How to get the value from each index?

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

I'm extremely new to Java and we're tasked to take random values of an array and pass them through a method where it adds all of them for a running total.

For the sumMethod I'd like to take each value from all the index (given by sizeOfArray) and add them together.

Thank you!

```
public static void sumMethod(double[] arrayOfDoubles){
   //How to get the value from each indexes (given by sizeOfArray) and add them for the sum
   int arrayLength = arrayOfDoubles.length;
         
        System.out.println(arrayOfDoubles);
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {   
   //1-3: Set up Scanner object to collect user's input on the size of array.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How many double numerical entries do you have?");
   //4: Declare an array of size sizeOfArray
      int sizeOfArray = keyboard.nextInt();  
   
      //Initialize array
      double[] arrayOfDoubles;
      arrayOfDoubles = new double[sizeOfArray];   
   
      
      
   
      for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
      //5: Use the Random number Class and walk over the array 
         Random randomNum = new Random();       
         arrayOfDoubles[i] = randomNum.nextDouble(0.0 , 100.0);
      //6: Invoke SumMethod
         sumMethod(arrayOfDoubles); 
      }
      
     
      
      
   }
}
```

Comment: you get the value with `arrayOfDoubles[index]`. declare an `int sum = 0` variable outside the `foor loop`, then `sum += arrayOfDoubles[i]` inside your `for loop`. in the end do what you wanna do with the sum.

Comment: @EmadAli This should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry about that, i'm still unclear about which should be answers and what is comments, I had the idea an answer should be a full long detailed explanation, I see a lot of people giving short description in comment section.

Comment: @EmadAli No need to apologize. Comments are intended to ask the OP for clarification. If you are giving direct advice to how to solve the problem, that should go in a question. The best guidelines I can find are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) on [meta].

Comment: @EmadAli `giving direct advice to how to solve the problem [should] go in a question` *direct advice to how to solve a problem should go in an answer*…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void sumMethod(double[] arrayOfDoubles) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfDoubles.length; j++) {
            sum += arrayOfDoubles[j];
        }
    }
```

This will work too, if you are not familiar with the for-each loop yet.

Additionally, it is better to use arrayOfDoubles.length in the loop, in case you edit the code later, and change the size, or add or remove an element.

Answer (score 0):

For `sumMethod`, I'd say the first thing you could do is give it a return value rather than `void`, (`public static double sumMethod`). That way when you run that method in `main` you can hold onto the result it prints out.
I may be wrong but my understanding is that your goal is to take an array and sum up the values within. For that purpose, the following would be a way to do it.

```java
public static double sumMethod(double[] arrayOfDoubles) {
    double total = 0;
    for (double num : arrayOfDoubles) {
        total += num;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Our instructor restricted us to have the method return void as well as having the method print out all of the values in the array.